# How to convert string to int with error handling?

Tags: php

```
value = (int)'0'; //0;
value = (int)'error message'; //0
```

The same with intval.

But 0 is the valid integer, why do they return it in case of error? How to avoid it?

Comment: [Well documented behaviour](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are just casting a value into an int. You don't check its type.

If you want to check that a value is an int you can use is_int :

```
if (is_int($myVar)) { 
    ... do something 
}
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

Comment: Wrong but very close.   is_int('0');//false   ,  is_numeric('0'); //true . Thank you.

Comment: I said the type, '0' is not an int but a string

Comment: Yes, but I just  wanted to convert string to int.  The input is always string, thats why there is no need to check its type.

Comment: Ok I understand. Why didn't you say it in your question ? :)

Comment: I think I said in the title.  Ok, added the world 'convert', now it shoult be more understandable.